# Pygame not running on shell, only on _pycache_

Tags: python

I just recently installed pygame, I already checked to make sure it was the correct version and everything. Whenever I run the program in the IDLE shell, it gives me an error, but when I run it in *pycache* the program works fine. Can someone please explain why this is happening

EDIT: I just realized that when I changed the name from “pygame.py” to something else, it worked. Dunno why tho

Comment: What do you mean, run it in pycache?

Comment: The cache is probably holding an old version. Renaming finally invalidated that. You'd have must likely gotten the same result by just deleting the cache.